# SqlBulkCopy throws System.FormatException when running WriteToServer(DataTable)

Tags: c#, sql, csv, sqlbulkcopy, formatexception

Currently I'm writing a method to read data from a CSV file and import to a SQL table.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String line = null;
        int i = 0;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] data = line.Split(',');
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    foreach (object item in data)
                    {
                        DataColumn c = new DataColumn(Convert.ToString(item));
                        if (Convert.ToString(item).Contains("DATE"))
                        {
                            c.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
                        }
                        else { c.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"); }
                        dt.Columns.Add(c);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Columns[j].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
                        {
                            row[j] = Convert.ToDateTime(data[j]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row[j] = data[j];
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constant.CONNECTION_STRING_NAME].ConnectionString);
        SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        s.DestinationTableName = "abc";
        con.Open();
        s.WriteToServer(dt);
```

The problem when running this method, an Exception is always thrown at s.WriteToServer(dt); saying

System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.

I debugged and see all the data were loaded into DataTable correctly.
Here is an example of a data row in my CSV file

```
DATA_VENDOR_ID,DATA_VENDOR_SUB_ID,DATA_VENDOR_CLIENT_ID,DATA_VENDOR_ACTIVITY_CODE,ACTIVITY_NAME,EFFECTIVE_DATE,ACTIVITY_LEVEL1,ACTIVITY_LEVEL2,ACTIVITY_LEVEL3,ACTIVITY_LEVEL4,ACTIVITY_LEVEL5,PARTICIPANT_ID,DATA_VENDOR_ALT_ID,FILE_CREATION_DATE,INC_VALUE    
V01,,22097,ABCD01,Physical Activity,10/01/2010,Entertain Kiosk,ABCD - EFG 54,30,,AB01,W1234567891,,08/07/2006,100
```

and my SQL table schema:

```
RowID   int Unique/AutoIncrement
DataVendorId    varchar(32) 
DataVendorSubId varchar(32) 
DataVendorClientId  varchar(32) 
DataVendorActivityCode  varchar(32) 
ActivityName    varchar(64) 
EffectiveDate   datetime    
ActivityLevel1  varchar(253)    
ActivityLevel2  varchar(253)    
ActivityLevel3  varchar(253)    
ActivityLevel4  varchar(253)    
ActivityLevel5  varchar(253)    
ParticipantID   varchar(32) 
DataVendorAltId varchar(32) 
FileCreationDate    datetime    
IncValue    varchar(5)  
CreatedDate datetime    optional/allow null
ModifiedDate    datetime    optional/allow null
```

Comment: btw, it is **far** more efficient to use `typeof(string)` than `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` - ditto `typeof(DateTime)`

Comment: thanks a lot for your recommendation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you're going to have problems with the `RowID` column; I expect it is trying to offset your data by one column at the moment - it *doesn't know* that you are omitting it. You can either mess with the mappings, or (in your data-table) add a `RowID` column (at index 0) - but note that SQL Server will ignore the values unless you enable identity-insert.

Perhaps try a more explicit datetime conversion:

```
row[j] = DateTime.ParseExact(data[j], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that I can't tell from the data if that is dd/MM or MM/dd, so you may need to tweak that.

Comment: You're right, I tried adding a dummy column for RowID and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where columns were off and once I defined the mapping, no problems:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDatabase"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {
                sbc.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTable";
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("foo", "bar");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("hello", "world");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("col1", "col2");
                sbc.WriteToServer(data);
            }
```

Also, I've got a List to DataTable converter extension that I use to convert my List.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = GetDataValue(prop.GetValue(item));
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

The GetDataValue() method cleans up my data for MinValue dates, etc:

```
private static object GetDataValue(object value)
        {
            if (value == null || (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime) && Convert.ToDateTime(value) == DateTime.MinValue) || (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime) && Convert.ToDateTime(value) < Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1753")))
            {
                return DBNull.Value;
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields in your data file doesn't match the table, i.e., you are trying to insert the `DataVendorId` into the `RowId` column which causes the exception as you cannot convert a `varchar(32)` to an `int`.

Move your identity column to the end of the table. Now the Bulk Insert will be able to match all the fields *until* it reaches the identify column.